# Why am i Getting garbage value when reading a binary file?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, binaryfiles

For the sake of simplicity I wrote a simple code to reproduce my problem. As you can see on the code i created a struct with two members then I created and array of the struct type then initialized it `student newStudent[3] ={{"joseph",20}, {"yonas",30},{"miryam",40}};`. I stored all the info from the struct to a binary file `newFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(newStudent), 3 * sizeof(student));`(everything is fine until here) then i created another array `student loadedStudent[3];` to load into, all the data from the binary file and output the loaded data using a for loop `cout<<"Name: "<<loadedStudent[i].name<<"Age: "<<loadedStudent[i].age<<endl;`. The problem is that the data i stored is `joseph",20, "yonas",30,"miryam",40` but the program is outputting garbage values `Name: 8H???Age: 1 Name: J???Age: 1 Name: ?I???Age: 32766`.
Why is that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct student{
    char name[10];
    int age;
};

int main()
{
    student newStudent[3] ={{"joseph",20}, {"yonas",30},{"miryam",40}};

    fstream newFile;
    newFile.open("/Users/josephfeleke/Desktop/abeltest/file.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);

//for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
        //cout<<"Name: "<<newStudent[i].name<<" Age: "<<newStudent[i].age<<endl;
    //}

    if(newFile.is_open()){

       newFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(newStudent), 3 * sizeof(student));

    }else cout<<"faild to open file";
   
    student loadedStudent[3];
    newFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);

    if(newFile.is_open()){

       newFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(loadedStudent), 3 * sizeof(student));
       newFile.close();

    }else cout<<"faild to open file";

    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){

        cout<<"Name: "<<loadedStudent[i].name<<"Age: "<<loadedStudent[i].age<<endl;
    }
```

Comment: What are the expected file content? I think you are printing pointer adresses instead if the content.

Comment: @zerocukor287
The expected file contents are strings and integer values, Should i dereference the outputs?

Comment: You're printing the indeterminate values of an uninitialized array. The file is only opened for writing. If you had taken a few seconds and added a check of whether reading succeeds, you would have noticed that it doesn't.

Comment: @molbdnilo
Yes you are right, Thank you so much brother. How do i mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you opened the file you only opened it as output `ios::out` you shoul've also included `ios::in` so you can access the file. Now you're printing the indeterminate values of an uninitialized array.

change this

```
newFile.open("/Users/josephfeleke/Desktop/abeltest/file.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);
```

into

```
newFile.open("/Users/josephfeleke/Desktop/abeltest/file.bin", ios::out | ios::in | ios::binary);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newFile.open("/Users/josephfeleke/Desktop/abeltest/file.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);
```

This is opening the  file for output only. You need `ios::in | ios::out` to be able to both read and write.